# I am trying to insert multiple input value with same name

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am trying to insert multiple fields with same name. For example I have multiple input fields with same name. Is it possible in PHP.

```
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="username">
so how can i insert these multiple value with same  name 

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$data = array(  
        'store_id' =>$id,  
        'username' =>$username
    );  
    $insert=$wpdb->insert('diary_user_form_storage', $data);
        if($insert){
            echo "Data Inserted";   
        }
        else{
            echo 'An error occurred';
        }
```

Comment: `<input type="text" name="username[]">`

Comment: Ok  and what will be php query

Comment: You will get all values in `$_POST['username']`.. It will be an array.

Comment: please check its allready in a array

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make this change:

```
<input type="text" name="username[]">
```

And

```
foreach($_POST['username'] as $key => $value) {
    $username = isset($value) ? $value : '';
    $data = array(  
        'store_id' =>$id,  
        'username' =>$username
    );  
    $insert=$wpdb->insert('diary_user_form_storage', $data);
    if($insert){
        echo "data inserted ";   
    }
    else{
        echo 'please solve the eroor';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your input name like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username[]">
```

And mysql query will be:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 );
```

You can refer this [url](https://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/58/adding-unlimited-form-fields-with-jquery-mysql/):